# Animated textures on a mesh plane?

Tags: texturing

I have a flat plane and a series of .png images that I want to have displayed on my plane as an animation.  I don't really know how to achieve this, as I've tried using "Image Sequence" on a Image texture node in the Materials section, which didn't work.  I enabled the AnimAll addon, but I cannot seem to find any tutorials that use the newest version of Blender (I'm using 2.91).

I'm relatively new to Blender, so any help is appreciated!

Comment: An image sequence used as texture for the shader should work fine. Please add more detail on what you did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The images have to be named with the same base name followed by a number.

[image]

The simplest way to import them into blender is to use the Import Images as Planes addon.

File > Import > Images as planes.

[image]

Select the images you want.

Press <kbd>N</kbd> or click on the gear icon on the right of the window to enable the options and select *Animate Image Sequences*

[image]

[image]

Or manually add an image sequence node Add > Texture > Image Sequence. Set the number of frames and start frame.

Then just enable *Auto Refresh*.

To have the images on a loop, use *Cyclic*

[image]